# Mirror npm packages

Tags: package-manager

We are using `npm` in our project. The policy of the company is that we cannot reference anything on the internet after release - to make sure our release is reproducible. We need to mirror all the npm packages locally.
What is the modern way to do that and what software should I use for this? I've tried to look at `npm-mirror` but it seems to be old and not updated.

Requirements:

1. The mirror should be deployed internally in our network.
2. It should support all npm packages. We should be able to select packages and versions to store

Comment: The `package-lock.json` file is used for this exact purpose, built-in into npm.

Comment: @Alejandro If I understand this correctly, this does not fit into policy. `package-lock` locks the versions and hashes, so if library is changed externally, without modifying the  version (particular case that is targeted by this policy) - we will not be able to build. This is good in terms that we will notice, but bad in terms that we will not be able to build the project anymore

Comment: @Alejandro One of the reasons why this policy was invented, is that there is a risk that the library located somewhere not on our servers is changed, and that corrupts our ability to reproduce issue. It is also a security risk in general

Comment: I think I'll rephrase the question (so it fits better) and ask it on SO, as it seems not to get enough attention here

Comment: Not only that, but also ensures that you get the very same versions of everything on each `npm install`. Yes, they're still downloaded over and over again from internet, the hashes help ensure nobody alters the libraries both in-transit and on the servers. This is enough as long as you trust Microsoft not to modify old versions of already published packages.

Comment: If you cannot trust that, you should not use `npm` at all (or any package manager for that matters), and download libraries the normal way, go to their site, download the binaries/code and commit those to source control.

Comment: @Alejandro Unfortunately keeping `node_modules` in the repository generally does not work. First it corrupts source control history by adding a lot of file changes whenever I change the package configuration, second - because `node_modules` is environment specific, I cannot call `npm install` on one machine and expect this folder to work on another machine in general